# Meaning of the term 'plotless'

Tags: anime-production

I need an elaborate answer to this question. After one of the answers I got from another question where a particular film jargon ("plotless story") was used, I read a [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plot_(narrative)) and found that plot (narrative) means the chain of events which are linked to each other. In every show which is made for entertainment, there must be a link between events otherwise it would make no sense to watch it. Imagine a hypothetical "plotless show" where two characters completed unrelated to each other, die because of completely unrelated reasons, it'd rather be called a set of random events rather than a show.

When people say "this anime has no plot", what do they actually mean? Are they talking about two episodes not connected to each other?

Comment: Your question is off-topic unless you can relate it back to a particular series or trope. You should have at least tried linking to the particular wiki page. Please consider editing your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is that unclear, but it is very broad. Short answer: the term doesn't mean what the literal definition of "plot" implies it should mean. It means a story that lacks an overarching narrative. A plotless show still has continuity, even between episodes in most cases, but it does not lay out a single self-contained chain of events. There's no culmination or payoff coming at the end.

Comment: @ʞɹɐzǝɹ Is this alright now? I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@torisuda has it correct:

> It means a story that lacks an overarching narrative

For an example of a *plotless* show, see Lucky Star.

The characters are the same in each scene, but every scene is **distinct** from each other. In one scene they might be talking about how to eat a chocolate cornet, another they might be talking about video games.

There are jokes that are referred to again - for example how Kagami is a tsundere. But this isn't a **narrative** or simply put - a story.

Your definition of narrative is correct:

> the chain of events which are linked to each other

but, it fails to contextualize the **links**. the links are items that further the plot's progression - for example: a hero beats a villain who was blocking the path, the girls perform in a concert that raises their fame, etc.

Links like reusing jokes, same characters - or generally things of **no overall consequence** do not contribute to the story/plot.

If we have no links like we described, the show can be called **plotless**.

Feel free to comment if you want me to expand on something.

Comment: And here I was waiting with my answer ever since I cast my reopen vote, just to have you jump right in :L You've described things better than I would have anyway, +1

Comment: ;) the more answers the better :)

Comment: @Matt If you look at our Area 51 stats, the one place we're lagging is number of answers per question, so if you have a slightly different way of looking at this, by all means post your answer.